# I can't get ShoesRB to install in Ubuntu 14. Is the issue the .run or .install file types?

Tags: ruby, linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, shoes

Whenever I attempt to open the ShoesRB install files for Linux, which are both "script.run" and "script.install" files, they open in a text editor instead of an installer. When I attempt to run them in the terminal, I'm getting strange root authentication errors. I know the root password is correct.

Does anybody know how to correctly install ShoesRB in Ubuntu 14?

Answer (score 2):

First of all download the executable from http://shoesrb.com/downloads/ according to your linux machine. This you have already done. On double clicking the downloaded .run file (say filename.run), you might not be able to run it because it would not be having executable permission -

This you can change by right clicking the script -> properties -> permissions -> Check the 'Allow executing file permission'
Or
from terminal by

```
chmod +x filename.run
```

Next you need to run this by:

```
sudo ./filename.run
```

Enter correct root password and you are good to go. This script actually make a hidden .shoes directory in your home and all shoes related files and executable are present in there. It also copies a desktop entry for shoes to /user/share/application, which you open to open shoes applications.

Moreover you can copy that desktop entry to your desktop and make it executable by:

```
cp /usr/share/applications/shoes.desktop ~/Desktop/shoes.desktop
chmod +x ~/Desktop/shoes.desktop
```

All done! Just double click the shoes icon on your desktop you can open your shoes apps now.
Hope it Helps :)